# What does /R mean in snort's pcre rule option?

Tags: pcre, snort

I'm trying to generate some traces that can trigger snort's alert to test the performance of snort. But there are some pcre options in some rules that contain /R, which I don't understand.

For example, there's a pcre option in one snort rule pcre: `"/^(\x75|\x2d|\x2f|\x73|\xa2|\x2e|\x24|\x74)/sR"`, and I don't know what **"R"** means there. I know **"s"** is a pcre modifier that can set PCRE_DOTALL. But what about **"R"**? Is it a modifier too or something else?

I've searched the pcre doc, but I didn't find there's an "R" modifier. So I think it's not a modifier.

Here's an example rule that contains pcre option with /R in it, I got this rule from snort3's community rules.

> alert udp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HOME_NET 138 ( msg:"OS-WINDOWS
>   Microsoft Windows SMB unicode andx invalid server name share access";
>   content:"|11|",depth 1; content:"|00|",distance 13;
>   content:"|00|",distance 0; content:"|FF|SMB",within 4,distance 3;
>   pcre:"/^(\x75|\x2d|\x2f|\x73|\xa2|\x2e|\x24|\x74)/sR";
>   byte_test:1,&,128,6,relative; content:"u",depth 1,offset 39;
>   byte_jump:2,0,little,relative; byte_jump:2,7,little,relative;
>   content:"|5C 00 5C 00|",distance 2,nocase;
>   pcre:!"/^([^\x5C\x00].|[\x5c\x00][^\x00])+\x5C\x00/sR";
>   metadata:policy max-detect-ips drop; reference:cve,2010-0022;
>   reference:url,technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/MS10-012;
>   classtype:protocol-command-decode; sid:16403; rev:12; )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `R` modifier is not a native PCRE modifier, it is a *Snort specific modifier for PCRE* regex, that enables Snort3 to force specific pattern behavior.

See [Snort3 "*3.5.26.1 Format*" documentation](http://manual-snort-org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node163.html):

> R            Match relative to the end of the last pattern match. (Similar to distance:0;)
> ...
> The modifiers R (relative) and B (rawbytes) are not allowed with any of the HTTP modifiers such as U, I, P, H, D, M, C, K, S and Y.

Note that acc. to [*Rules Authors Introduction to Writing Snort 3 Rules*](https://snort-org-site.s3.amazonaws.com/production/document_files/files/000/000/252/original/Rules_Writers_Guide_to_Snort_3_Rules.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIXACIED2SPMSC7GA%2F20200903%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200903T085548Z&X-Amz-Expires=172800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=5fd9e4ea847a4eb0296cc50b6ab78d627cb922b4f7fc3e6f7f16a045ef520256):

> In Snort 2, the post-re modifiers (`B`, `U`, `P`, `H`, `M`, `C`, `I`, `D`, `K`, `S`, `Y`) set compile time flags for the regular expression. For example, the Snort specific modifier for pcre U is used to match the decoded URI buffers.
>
> In Snort 3, some of post-re modifiers (`B`, `U`, `P`, `H`, `M`, `C`, `I`, `D`, `K`, `S`, `Y`) have been deleted in favor of sticky
> buffers.